# Tensorflow pruned model is the same size as original baseline model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pruning

I have a baseline TF functional model that I want to prune. I have tried following the code in the documentation, but the size the compressed pruned model is the same size as the compressed baseline model.

(https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/comprehensive_guide#export_model_with_size_compression)

I don't believe there is anything wrong with my code, so why does this occur?

```
def get_gzipped_model_size(model):
  # Returns size of gzipped model, in bytes.
  import os
  import zipfile

  _, keras_file = tempfile.mkstemp('.h5')
  model.save(keras_file, include_optimizer=False)

  _, zipped_file = tempfile.mkstemp('.zip')
  with zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_file, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as f:
    f.write(keras_file)

  return os.path.getsize(zipped_file)


def test():
    model = keras.models.load_model('models/cifar10/baselines/convnet_small')
    model_for_pruning = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude(model)

    model_for_export = tfmot.sparsity.keras.strip_pruning(model_for_pruning)

    print("Size of gzipped baseline model: %.2f bytes" % (get_gzipped_model_size(model)))
    print("Size of gzipped pruned model without stripping: %.2f bytes" % (get_gzipped_model_size(model_for_pruning)))
    print("Size of gzipped pruned model with stripping: %.2f bytes" % (get_gzipped_model_size(model_for_export)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Output:

```
Size of gzipped baseline model: 604286.00 bytes

Size of gzipped pruned model without stripping: 610750.00 bytes

Size of gzipped pruned model with stripping: 604287.00 bytes
```

*EDIT:*

I also tried this with the same model as in the documentation, and the pruned model is still the same size as the baseline:

```
input_shape = [20]
x_train = np.random.randn(1, 20).astype(np.float32)
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randn(1), num_classes=20)


def setup_model():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, input_shape=input_shape),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
  ])
  return model

def setup_pretrained_weights():
  model = setup_model()

  model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
      optimizer='adam',
      metrics=['accuracy']
  )

  model.fit(x_train, y_train)

  _, pretrained_weights = tempfile.mkstemp('.tf')

  model.save_weights(pretrained_weights)

  return pretrained_weights


setup_model()
pretrained_weights = setup_pretrained_weights()
```

Output:

```
Size of gzipped baseline model: 2910.00 bytes
Size of gzipped pruned model without stripping: 3333.00 bytes
Size of gzipped pruned model with stripping: 2910.00 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are missing the step that actually does the pruning. If we look at the `test()` function, you set the model up for pruning but never actually prune it. Look at the edits below.

```
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

def test():
    model = keras.models.load_model('models/cifar10/baselines/convnet_small')
    pruning_schedule = tfmot.sparsity.keras.ConstantSparsity(
                         target_sparsity=0.95, 
                         begin_step=0, 
                         end_step=-1, 
                         frequency=100
                        )

    callbacks = [tfmot.sparsity.keras.UpdatePruningStep()]
    model_for_pruning = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude(base_model, pruning_schedule=pruning_schedule)
    model_for_pruning.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="some-loss")
    model_for_pruning.fit(X, y, epochs=2, callbacks=callbacks)
    model_for_export = tfmot.sparsity.keras.strip_pruning(model_for_pruning)


    print("Size of gzipped baseline model: %.2f bytes" %(get_gzipped_model_size(model)))
    print("Size of gzipped pruned model without stripping: %.2f bytes" % (get_gzipped_model_size(model_for_pruning)))
    print("Size of gzipped pruned model with stripping: %.2f bytes" % (get_gzipped_model_size(model_for_export)))
```

You can take a look at the code I have in a question I just asked. I am having a slightly different problem but the code posted there works (at least for some of the cases).

[Why is my pruned model larger than my base model when using Tensorflow's Model Optimization library to prune weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922976/why-is-my-pruned-model-larger-than-my-base-model-when-using-tensorflows-model-o)

You can also check out the `tensorflow.sparsity.keras` APIs to see some of the other options if you are interested

https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot/sparsity/keras